# Merge Dataframes on basis of coordinates having no common columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geometry

INPUT :

df1

```
Pg  x0      y0      x1      y1      Text
1   521.3   745.92  537.348 754.097 word1
1   538.982 745.92  580.247 754.097 word2
1   527.978 735.253 572.996 747.727 word3
2   268.985 732.36  341.59  746.636 word4
2   344.443 732.36  390.175 746.636 word5
```

df2

```
Pg  x0      y0      x1      y1      Text                T   R   C
1   507.6   730.8   593.76  754.8   word1 word2 word3   1   1   2
2   334.56  732.36  401.34  746.636 word5               2   3   1
```

Expected OUTPUT :

```
Pg  x0      y0      x1      y1      Text    T   R   C
1   521.3   745.92  537.348 754.097 word1   1   1   2
1   538.982 745.92  580.247 754.097 word2   1   1   2
1   527.978 735.253 572.996 747.727 word3   1   1   2
2   268.985 732.36  341.59  746.636 word4           
2   344.443 732.36  390.175 746.636 word5   2   3   1
```

I need to find which all words in df1 are present in df2 on basis of coordinates(overlap) and **not Text** based approach. After this I need to copy the values of columns [T, R, C] from df2 to df1.

For eg : First row of df2 has coordinates that overlap the coordinates of the word1, word2, word3 of df1. Overlap here means the bbox(x0, y0, x1, y1) of a row in df1 should lie inside the bbox(x0, y0, x1, y1) of a specific row of df2.

My Approach :

I am iterating each row in df2 and then comparing each row coordinate from df1 to find any overlaps and then merging the dataframes.

```
for i, r in df2.iterrows():
    df1.loc[
                (df1.x0 >= r.x0) &
                (df1.y0 >= r.y0) &
                (df1.x1 <= r.x1) &
                (df1.y1 <= r.y1) , 'flag'] = 1

    df1.loc[df.flag == 1, ['T', 'R', 'C']] = r.T, r.R, r.C
```

Problem is the whole process is working properly as expected but takes a lot of time to run. It takes around `90 seconds` to run df1 = 20,000 rows and df2 = 3500 rows.

Comment: Can you post your working code that merges the dataframes so we can make specific recommendations on how to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and masking. Example:

```
def compare(row):
    mask = df2[
        (df2['x0'] <= row['x0']) &
        (df2['x1'] >= row['x1']) &
        (df2['y0'] <= row['y0']) &
        (df2['y1'] >= row['y1'])
    ]
    if mask.empty:
        return row
    row['T'] = mask['T'].tolist()[0]
    row['R'] = mask['R'].tolist()[0]
    row['C'] = mask['C'].tolist()[0]

return row

result = df1.apply(compare, axis=1)
```